# Difference between object type definitions in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

We've been working on a larger project and different developers seem to use different type definitions for a fairly plane object, more precisely two versions stood out. Can anybody explain main differences, benefits, and implications of using either version?

```js
type MyObject = { [_: string]: string | number }
type MyObjectAlternative = Record<string, string | number>
```

Cheers

Comment: The first line is a literal implementation of the second one, you can check it by looking for definition of `Record`.

Comment: I believe `Record` was something Typescript didn't initially have, so creating simple types for Objects used the first version.   IOW: it could be partially legacy reasons the first version exists.  Edit, just checked, it wasn't until version 2.1 the Record type was introduced.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Comment: Thx guys, are there advantages of using one version over another?

Comment: Only code readability,  I would say the `Record` is just a tad easier, before using it, I always seemed to have to lookup again how to do it.  Since using `Record` I've not needed too.

Comment: @Cerberus these both types are different. In Record, you can use a union of strings to represent keys, while in MyObject you can't use unions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between both types.

```js
type MyObject = { [_: string]: string | number }
type MyObjectAlternative = Record<string, string | number>
```

You can't use unions in `MyObject` ( in TypeScript before 4.4):

```js
type MyObject = { [_: string | number ]: string | number } // error
type MyObjectAlternative = Record<'a'|'b', string | number> // ok

type MyObject = { [_: 'a'|'b' ]: string | number } // error
type MyObjectAlternative = Record<'a'|'b', string | number> // ok
```

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead

From T.4.4 (currently beta) you can use union as a type of a key in MyObject.

```js
type MyObject = { [_: string | number | symbol]: string | number } // allowed
type MyObjectAlternative = keyof Record<'a' | 'b', string | number> // ok

type Keys = {
    [Prop in keyof MyObject]: Prop
}

type Keys2 = {
    [Prop in keyof MyObjectAlternative]: Prop
}
```

As you might have noticed, `keyof MyObject` and `keyof MyObjectAlternative` operators works differently in both cases.

`MyObjectAlternative` is more treated like regular object in javascript with all built in properties, while `MyObject` is treated as object without prototype.

Also, since TS 4.4 we can mix template literal strings:

```js
type MyObject = { [_:  `data-${string}`]: string | number } // ok
```

But please keep in mind

```js
type MyObject = { [_:  'a'|'b']: string | number } // error
```

union of literals still disallowed

[Typescript 4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#symbol-template-signatures)

Comment: This is wrong, they are the same, see the definition of `Record`. In your second example, you used `string | number` for type literal, but for `Record` you used strings only. This `type T1 = { [_:n any ]: string | number }` is wrong, but this: `type T2 = { [_ in string | number ]: any }`, is ok.

Comment: See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3lA2gfQFxQM7ABOAlgHYDmUAPlKQK4C2ARhIVALq4EkXW2Ms2AXygB6UVFaEA9oQBQoSLABMSVBkxQy+ImUo16zVhy67eBgcZHio0gNYLw0GAGY1AJQgBjWQBMAPNx6fIaCADQ6PPr8RoQAfGIS9kA

Comment: @Akxe In your exmaple T1 is not the same as T2 or T3. I don't understand what you mean. `Keys` and `Keys2` was provided to show how `keyof` operator works with different types. Because Record differs from indexed type, `Keys` and `Keys2` are completely different. Please hover you mouse on both of them

Answer (score 1):

`Record` is the same as type literal. If you look at the definition of `Record` you will see this:

```
/**
 * Construct a type with a set of properties K of type T
 */
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
```

Comment: It is not the same, because to define Record you use `[P in K]` while to define indexed object you use `[prop: string]`.